# Como impedir que as paginas sejam carregadas pelo navegador apos encerrar a sessão

Tags: php, session

Estou tentando fazer um site acadêmico onde os usuários precisam se logar (pagina de login :pagina.php) ai será direcionado a pagina(nome.php) onde faz a conexão com o banco e se tiver o cadastro vai para a pagina site.php, e depois onde fará o logout(logoutt.php), mas quando faço o logout e aperto o botão de voltar do navegador (em vez de me direcionar para de login onde deveria logar novamente), esta indo para a pagina (site.php). Se puderem me ajudar Agradeço.

Obs: Ainda estou aprendendo, este site é mais para aprender na pratica`

```html
Pagina de login:

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="login">
    <form method="POST" action= 'nome.php'>
<label class="bottom">Login: </label><input type="text" name="login" id="login"><br>
<label>Senha: </label><input type="password" name="senha" id="senha"><br>
<input type="submit" value="login" id="login" name="login">
</form>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>

pagina enquanto estar logado:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <?php
session_start();
if((!isset ($_SESSION['login'])) and (!isset ($_SESSION['senha'])))
{
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);
    header('location:index.php');
    }
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SISTEMA WEB</title>
</head>
 
<body>
<table width="800" height="748" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="90" colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">SISTEM WEB TESTE
      
 Olá <?$_SESSION['login']?>! <a href="logoutt.php"/>Logout!</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="103" height="410" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">MENU AQUI</td>
    <td width="546">CONTEUDO E ICONES AQUI</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#000000"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Pagina de logout:

<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
unset($_SESSION["login"]);
unset($_SESSION["senha"]);
session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só colocar uma função de proteção em cada pagina que deve ser protegida. exemplo

```
<?php     
  if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header('Location: /pagina.php');
    exit();
  }    
?>
```

Se não existir `$_SESSION['id'];` ele manda o cara para */pagina.php*

assim que o cara digitar o login e senha corretos, ponha o ID do banco da linha do banco de dados, no `$_SESSION['id']`

e quando o cara acessar o *logou.php* basta destruir a sessão usando `session_detroy();` e em seguida por um `header('Location: /pagina.php');`